# Double Click On A WebElement in an iframe nested in an other iframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Basically, my page has the following spec:

```
<html>
   ...
   <iframe id="lvl1">
       <html>
           <iframe id="lvl2">
               <div>Double Click Me !</div>
           </iframe>
       </html>
   <iframe>
</html>
```

I can't manage to double click on the given element (using ActionChain) because when I do a MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException is thrown.

```
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    from selenium.common.exceptions import MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException

    try:
        action = ActionChains(context.browser)
        action.double_click(webelement)
        action.perform()
    except MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException:
        context.browser.switch_to_default_content()
        context.browser.switch_to_frame("lvl1")
        context.browser.switch_to_frame("lvl2")
        actions = ActionChains(context.browser)
        my_locationXY = emoji.get_location()
        actions.move_to_element_with_offset(frame, my_locationXY["x"], my_locationXY["y"]).double_click().perform()
```

I based the previous snippet on the last comment posted [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4863).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method posted in the above link was the good one in fact. The issue that my current selected frame was not the n-1 th frame and that I needed an explicit reference to the n-th frame (the one where my element is)

```
location = (element.location['x'] + element.size['width'] / 2, element.location['y'] + element.size['height'] / 2)

#Switching to the n-1 th frame, frames is an array of frames' name
frames = page.frame

browser.switch_to_default_content()
for frameName in frames[:len(frames) - 1]:
    browser.switch_to_frame(frameName)

#Handle to the n th frame
frame = browser.find_element_by_tag_name(name="iframe")
action = ActionChains(context.browser)
action.move_to_element_with_offset(frame, location[0], location[1]).double_click()
action.perform()
```